# How do I type in my password or some other commands in my terminal/command prompts?

Tags: laravel, cmd, terminal, command, prompt

I've been trying to run some commands on my command prompt/terminal, but after each command, it won't let me type anymore.

Take this as an example.
I was trying to clear cache and it asked for my password, but when i try to type in my password, it doesn't respond. But once i click on "enter" it'll show a different password and say it's incorrect.

I was trying to clear cache for a laravel project I'm working on.
I was trying to clear cache and it asked for my password, but when i try to type in my password, it doesn't respond. But once i click on "enter" it'll show a different password and say it's incoorect.[image: This is the screenshot before i click on enter]

And here's it after i click on "enter".
[image: Here's it after i click on enter]

Note that 1326 wasn't the password that i entered.

Comment: Where's my microscope?

Comment: `1326` is the error number (plus translation to human readable text). You **do** have the password for the `Administrator` user? It's (usually) different from yours.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.